# Visual Studio 2019 VB.net Frameworks 3.5 change to 4.5 - opens only in development Folder

Tags: vb.net

Visual Studio 2019 VB.net

In 08/2021 I compiled a program in the original development folder (A).

Then copied to another folder (B) and opened the program. Everything OK.

In 09/2021 I only made one change. Frameworks 3.5 to 4.5. In folder (A) opens OK.

If I copy the program to folder (B) the program does not open and does not report any errors.

In fact, other users who use this program cannot open it.

I have installed Frameworks update 4.7+

What can it depend on?

Thank you for specific help.

Raimund
.

Comment: What does "copy the program" and "open the program" mean? Copying and/or opening the Solution/Project (source code) or copying and/or running the compiled .EXE?

Comment: Only the EXE File.

Comment: You'll need to add more information. Are you copying everything from the `bin\deug` or `bin\release` path? What error message are users getting?

Comment: As mentioned i'm only copying the Exe-File and *.pdb file and the files the program needs. Nothing else.

Comment: Meanwhile i opened the program with Visual Studio 2017 and it opens with the FrameWorks 3.5. With Visual Studio 2019 i can't get back to fm 3.5 even when i set it.

Comment: When i open with V Studio 2019 it declares immediately again fm 4.0.  I resolved half my problem becouse others can open it ì but this does not explain the Visual Studio 2019 problem using fm 4.0 i can only open within the \bin\x86\release folder.

Comment: Last comment. When i set the fm 4.0 back to 3.5 with Visual Studio 2019 i can open the program within the developement folder and also in a different folder (only the program) on my PC. other user can't open it. That makes me think.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Together with Microsoft the problem has been resolved. Microsoft is reading the same comments you are reading here. Anyhow, the problem is caused by the Compiler. Switching between 2 Frameworks is not that simple. Thanks for your interest and intervention.